# JavaFX directory chooser: How to hide files in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, file, javafx, javafx-8

I've used directory chooser to open a window that selects only folder. It works fine in windows, but in linux along with the folder it shows files in the directory(they are disabled for selection). Is it possible to hide the files?

```
    DirectoryChooser chooser = new DirectoryChooser();
    chooser.setTitle("Select Source Directory");
    File file = chooser.showDialog(new Stage());
    if (file != null) {
        isPathSelected = true;
        textField.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Example:

[image: example]